# Having empty output for selected node in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I have an XML file which includes some nodes and its children sometimes with the same name and attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
  <Address Type="Shipping">
    <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
    <City>Mill Valley</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Zip>10999</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Address>
  <Address Type="Billing">
    <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
    <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    <City>Old Town</City>
    <State>PA</State>
    <Zip>95819</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <Address Type="Buying">
        <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    </Address>
    <Address Type="transporting">
        <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
        <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    </Address>
  </Address>
  <DeliveryNotes>Please leave packages in shed by driveway.</DeliveryNotes>
  <Items>
    <Item PartNumber="872-AA">
      <ProductName>Lawnmower</ProductName>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
      <Comment>Confirm this is electric</Comment>
    </Item>
    <Item PartNumber="926-AA">
      <ProductName>Baby Monitor</ProductName>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
      <ShipDate>1999-05-21</ShipDate>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

I want to have just only the `Address` nodes with its attributes as output. The problem is that there are some nested nodes which have the `Address` node as a child. Getting access to the child `Address` is my problem. If again it has child with the name `Address` then I do not want to give me this node as I have done in the following code

```
public void find_node(string ID_node) 
{
    XElement root = XElement.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");
    IEnumerable<XElement> address =
        from el in root.Elements("Address")
        where (string)el.Attribute("Type") == "Buying"
        select el;

    foreach (XElement el in address)
    {
        var newElement = new XElement(
                                el.Name.LocalName,
                                el.Attributes(),
                                el.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName != "Address")
                         );
        Console.WriteLine(newElement.ToString());
    }
}
```

The desired output for this code would be

```
<Address Type="Buying">
    <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
</Address>
```

but it has empty output when I am running the above function.

May I ask you have could I get ride of empty output for this function?

Comment: Can you show us what is desired output?

Comment: @HariPrasad Please see the update version of Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to look for `Address` elements regardless of its location within the XML, as long as it matches the attribute filter, you can use `Descendants("Address")` instead :

```
IEnumerable<XElement> address =
                from el in root.Descendants("Address")
                where (string)el.Attribute("Type") == "Buying"
                select el;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<XElement> address =
            from el1 in root.Elements("Address")
            from el2 in el1.Elements("Address")
            where (string)el2.Attribute("Type") == "Buying"
            select el2;
```

Comment: In general this method would fail if the inner child is more deeper node. However it works fine for this example.